# scp + error Name or service not known + custom port

Tags: ssh, port, scp

I have read lot of post about this problem but i still can not solve it on my side.

I have a server i used to connect like this:

```
$ ssh user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx -p yy
```

> user = is not root
>
> xxx.xx.xx.xxx = ipv4 of my server
>
> yy = custom port for ssh

Connexion works well.

I try to make a copy of a folder from my local machine (ubuntu) to the server(ubuntu 14.04) like this:

```
$ scp -r -p /home/user/my/folder/ ssh://user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:yy/home/user/my/folder/on/server/
```

I get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

I guess the connexion works well. So what could happen? A problem with rights of the folder?

For information, my local machine get both ipv4 and ipv6 address. Could it be that?

Thank you in advance for any help.
jb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check manual page for `scp`. It describe the usage of `scp` with all the switches and options:

```
scp [...] [-P port] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Your command should be:

```
$ scp -r -p -P yy /home/user/my/folder/ user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:/home/user/my/folder/on/server/
```

Note port comes as `-P yy`, you don't write ssh:// in front the `user` and separate host from the remote path using colon (`:`).

Comment: it work perfectly. Thank you for the tip. Manual page [example]( http://marionpatrick.free.fr/man_html/html/scp_1.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "ssh://".

Here scp believes ssh is the name of the server you want to copy to. That's what the message says : "Could not resolve hostname ssh"

Try :

```
$ scp -r -p -P yy /home/user/my/folder/ user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx/home/user/my/folder/on/server/
```

Comment: i try without **ssh://** but i get this error: _ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused_ ... it try to connect on the classic port.

Comment: I edited my answer to add the option for a specific port